# Problems in calling Parse getdataInthebackground in a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, loadimage

Hi I am trying to query some files from my Parse database and I want the files to be sorted according to the updateAt time. I have the following code. The query works and the results are sorted according to my condition, but when I load the files using getDataInBackground and then add to an array. The files are not sorted and they appear to be random in the array.

So My questions are

1. What can I do to make sure the files in the array are in the same order as the query results?
2. Any way to check the files/images against the objectID in the completion block of getDataInBackground?

p.s. I don't want to use getData since I don't want it to block the main thread.

Thank you very much in advance

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
[query orderByDescending:@"updateAt"];    
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *photoStacks, NSError     *error) 
  {
     if (!error) {
     // The find succeeded.
    for (PFObject *photoImage in photoStacks) {
    PFFile *userImageFile = photoImage[@"image"];
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    // need to check object id before adding into the stack to make sure the order is right
                    [photoImageStacks addObject:image];
                    if ([photoImageStacks count] == photoStacksCount)
                    {
                        [photoPile setArray:photoImageStacks];
                    }


                }
            }];
        }

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }



}];
```

Comment: What are data types for these "photoImageStacks" and "photoPile" and where you are using this after response ?

Comment: Hi @bmindhackers, photoImageStacks and photoPile are both NSMutuableArray. The photoPile will be used by another class calling the method of this query code. But even if I just look at the array after setArray, I can see that the images loaded are not sorted accordingly.

Comment: this array of images will use in tableview cell? Download the image where you want to show that image on the display do not make array of that downloaded image.

Comment: @ Jamish, I would like to keep everything modular so I can avoid Parse function spreading everywhere on my program. Is there any other way you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

use breakpoint and trace first photoImageStacks and second after response you should call reload method if you are using tableview or some delegate or fire a notification so that you can update ui accordingly after successful response.

Comment: Thanks @bmindhackers, can you be more specific? Just to add more info regarding the problem, I think the second "getDataInBackground" command was sent and finished before the first "getDataInBackground" command came back. Probably the first image is much larger than the second one.